# Ruby on Rails. Few classes in the same file. "Uninitialized constant" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've defined a few Exception classes in my **app/models/core/exceptions.rb** file:

```
class Core::Exception < Exception end
class Core::UserNotFoundException < Core::Exception end
...
```

Then added **/config/initializers/require.rb** file so Rails can find classes with names which don't meet file names:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/app/models/core/exceptions.rb"
```

When I start the app (development mode), everything works fine until I change anything to any .rb file. Then when I refresh browser page I get error "Uninitialzed constant Core::Exception". So every time I make any modification to the source code (except the views) I have to restart 'rails server'.

Any idea on why when I refresh a page my 'require' are no longer loaded? How to fix this?

Comment: Where is the Core module defined?

Comment: There is no Core module, but the namespace. there are Core::Model classes, located in the /app/models/core folder

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `core.rb` file should help.

Just place the Core module definition there

```
# /app/models/core.rb
module Core
end
```

Comment: My models are namespaces, e.g. Core::Customer, they are located in the /app/models/core folder, as well as the exceptions.rb file. How does the "core.rb" file helps and what you think I should put into it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the `Core` module. When you hit

`class Core::Exception ...`

rails needs to find the module or class named Core. Rails will create a module called Core automatically if it finds files with paths off the form 'core/foo.rb' in its autoload path (see the algorithm pseudo code in the [guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#generic-procedure) on autoloading).

Because this `Core` module is autoloaded, code reloading will trigger its removal. A new `Core` module may be created, but this will no longer have the classes you had added to it.

One option would be to not fight Rails's code organisation and put those classes in individual files.

An alternative may be to change how you create those classes to

```
module Core
  class Exception < ::Exception; end
end
```

Which means that the Core module won't be autoloaded and thus shouldn't be eligible for removal.

Comment: well, my exceptions.rb file is already required in an initalizer file: require "#{Rails.root}/app/models/core/exceptions.rb", so it's loaded when app starts. Just wonder why it stops working after I change anything and send a new HTTP request. Maybe the initializer is not the right place for this, then what is? If there is no quick solution then probably I should stick to separate files for every Exception class.

Comment: @Serge The problem is not whether it's required or not, but that you've placed your classes in a module that will be removed by code reloading

Comment: So I have /app/models/core/customer.rb, etc. files, then /app/models/core/exceptions.rb with a few Exceptions. Is your advice that I have to create /app/models/core/core.rb file and place all the exceptions there, removing the namespace name from class names, like this: Core::Exception -> Exception?

Comment: No - my advice is to either use 1 file per class OR change exceptions.rb as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: adjusting exceptions.rb didn't help. Well, probably I should go for 1 file per class. Just wonder that there is no another solution